# Windows file manager with spider/map view

Tags: windows, file-management

Something that looks like this

[image: NexusFile screenshot]

That's from NexusFile, although it only allows you to view your folders like that, not manage them.

Comment: that's called tree view and almost every file manager, even Windows explorer, supports that

Comment: I totally agree - what are you actually asking here? And what do you mean by "managing" files?

Comment: You're saying this already exists but not telling me where to find it? Strange. How/where in windows explorer can I see my files and folders in that view and also move/delete/copy/rename them?

Comment: You can go into the siderbar of windows explorer and manually expand every folder but it will take long and look cluttered unlike what is shown where every level within a folder is shown and is zoomed out to show as much as possible, with lines to show relationships. The Windows file tree is verticle whilst what is show in the image is a horizontal tree.

Comment: the list in the above image and there's no horizontal scroll bar. You can enable the option to [make explorer expands the folders automatically](https://superuser.com/q/739922/241386) and IIRC there's an option to expand all folders at the same level

Comment: The defining feature of the image I posted is that it's a horizontal tree. It's completely different from what windows has and I'm surprised there was confusion. There's no horizontal bar in the pic because the the folders are not expanded. Windows explorer is garbage, vertical file management makes 0 sense when all our monitors are wider than they are tall.

Comment: Still, thanks for advising on how to expand all levels in windows explorer.